# How do you evaluate a java.lang.String in clojure

Tags: clojure

How would I eval to the following?

```
(defn run-clojure-func []
  (println "welcome"))

(defn -main [& args]
  (eval (*func* (first args)))

java exam.Hello "run-clojure-func"
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you ask in words? What is -main supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two versions for you to consider – entirely equivalent, but useful as points of comparison:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  ((-> args first symbol resolve)))
```

and this, using [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#let) and no [`->` macro](http://blog.fogus.me/2010/09/28/thrush-in-clojure-redux/) usage:

```
(defn -main [[fn-name]]
  ((resolve (symbol fn-name))))
```

`resolve` is obviously the key.  The docs are your friend. :-)  Also, as an unfair generalization, `eval` is almost never necessary.